# Javascript get value from object based on key compared to its size smaller then next key

Tags: javascript

Trying to calculate shipping prices based on the weight of a package.

I have an Object containing prices for a given weight like

```
shippingPrices = {
    'economy': {
         [weight]: price,
         . . . 
     }
};
```

Then I want to get the right shipping price with a function passing the weight of a package like:

```
addShippingPrice(700);  // 700 is weight in grams
```

I've tried like so:

```js
shippingPrices = {
    'economy': {
        2000: 7,
        5000: 9,
        10000: 10,
        20000: 15,
        30000: 22
    }
};

var addShippingPrice = function(weight) {
    var price = 0;
    for( var maxWeight in shippingPrices.economy) {
        maxWeight = parseInt(maxWeight, 10);
        
        console.log(shippingPrices.economy[maxWeight]);
      
        if(weight < maxWeight) {
            // return price = shippingPrices.economy[maxWeight];
        }
    }
    console.log('amount', price);
};

addShippingPrice(700);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The "right" shipping price in this case would be `7` and if I call the function with weight 8000 `addShippingPrice(8000);` it should return `10`

How can I achieve that? Also if it would be better to change the shippingPrices Object to Array I'll change it!

Comment: What if weight is 2001?

Comment: @NenadVracar going for price `9` => `5000: 9,` , 2000 would be 7, 2001 is to big for 2000 so it needs to take the next bigger possible...

Comment: Your code is all right,  what's the problem?

Comment: @georg I think the `return` is the problem, should of used `break` like in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterable structure, like

> ```
> var shippingPrices = {
>     economy: [
>         { weight: 2000, price: 7 },
>         { weight: 5000, price: 9 },
>         { weight: 10000, price: 10 },
>         { weight: 20000, price: 15 },
>         { weight: 30000, price: 22 }
>     ],
>     priority: [
>         { weight: 2000, price: 9 },
>         { weight: 5000, price: 11 },
>         { weight: 10000, price: 12 },
>         { weight: 20000, price: 18 },
>         { weight: 30000, price: 25 }
>     ]
> };
> ```

```js
function getShippingPrice(type, weight) {
    var price;
    shippingPrices[type].some(function (a) {
        if (a.weight >= weight) {
            price = a.price;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return price;
}

var shippingPrices = { economy: [{ weight: 2000, price: 7 }, { weight: 5000, price: 9 }, { weight: 10000, price: 10 }, { weight: 20000, price: 15 }, { weight: 30000, price: 22 }], priority: [{ weight: 2000, price: 9 }, { weight: 5000, price: 11 }, { weight: 10000, price: 12 }, { weight: 20000, price: 18 }, { weight: 30000, price: 25 }] };

console.log(getShippingPrice('economy', 700));
console.log(getShippingPrice('economy', 8000));
```

ES6

```js
function getShippingPrice(type, weight) {
    return (shippingPrices[type].find(a => a.weight >= weight) || {}).price;
}

var shippingPrices = { economy: [{ weight: 2000, price: 7 }, { weight: 5000, price: 9 }, { weight: 10000, price: 10 }, { weight: 20000, price: 15 }, { weight: 30000, price: 22 }], priority: [{ weight: 2000, price: 9 }, { weight: 5000, price: 11 }, { weight: 10000, price: 12 }, { weight: 20000, price: 18 }, { weight: 30000, price: 25 }] };

console.log(getShippingPrice('economy', 700));
console.log(getShippingPrice('economy', 8000));
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, really liking this! Didn't know about the `some` function

Comment: check my answer below, you don't need to change your data structure.

Comment: In case the input data is not sorted by weight you may get incorrect result, won't you?

Answer (score 1):

```js
shippingPrices = {
      'economy': {
        2000: 7,
        5000: 9,
        10000: 10,
        20000: 15,
        30000: 22
      },
      'priority': {
        2000: 9,
        5000: 11,
        10000: 12,
        20000: 18,
        30000: 25
      }
    };

    var addShippingPrice = function(weight) {
      var price = 0;
      for (var maxWeight in shippingPrices.economy) {
        maxWeight = parseInt(maxWeight);

        if (weight <= maxWeight) {
          price = shippingPrices.economy[maxWeight];
          break;
        }
      }
      return price;
    };

    var shipping_price = addShippingPrice(8000);
    console.log('amount', shipping_price);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to take that out. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on Object key sequence here, since as stated in the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order.

What you can do is to prepare an array of key weights and sort it. This array can be used then for comparison with the given value. Once you define the corresponding key weight, you'll ease get the price

```js
shippingPrices = {
    'economy': {
        2000: 7,
        5000: 9,
        10000: 10,
        20000: 15,
        30000: 22
    }
};

var getShippingPrice = function(weight) {
    var weights = [];
    for( var maxWeight in shippingPrices.economy) {
        weights.push(parseInt(maxWeight, 10));
    }
    weights.sort(function(a,b){
      return a - b;
    });
  
    for (var i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
      if (weights[i] >= weight) {
        return shippingPrices.economy[weights[i]];
      }
    } 
    return 0; // or return Math.max.apply(null, weights);
};

console.log('19000 => ', getShippingPrice(19000));
console.log('5000 => ', getShippingPrice(5000));
console.log('5001 => ', getShippingPrice(5001));
```

BTW, don't give name such "add..." to function which should just return a value

Comment: So you mean like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39545375/2008111 by `Nina Scholz` or would you write different code? If different, you might show it?

Comment: @caramba, see my variant

Comment: Yes, thank you! I don't like the use of two for loops, pushing something to new array which already kinda exists...

Comment: @caramba, it is only an example of implementation. The way of implementation depends on lots of factors I don't know basing on the description of the topic. However even so you don't like it ;) you have to either provide the array as input data, or do the loop, create the array and store it globally to prevent from repeating. My example will work with any input data meanwhile this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/39545375/2008111 works only with prepared input data (it should be sorted in advance)

Answer (score 0):

use below code, in case of maximum weight goes beyond the defined weight in object, you can set default Value for such case.

```
shippingPrices = {
            'economy': {
                2000: 7,
                5000: 9,
                10000: 10,
                20000: 15,
                30000: 22
            }
        };

        var addShippingPrice = function (weight) {
            $.each(shippingPrices.economy, function (key, value) {
                if (weight <= key) {
                    console.log(value);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        };

        addShippingPrice(700); // 7
        addShippingPrice(8000); // 10
```